# Add extra cells with each entry to table output

Tags: r, excel, shiny

I am trying to make an xlsx sheet of customers orders of certain items. I created a shiny app to input each order in the form of a datatable row which is added to the table on click of "Add" Button. But I face a problem, each time I add a new order (row) an extra cell of row number is generated in all the previous ones like in the picture.[image]
and all row cells are shifted to the right!!

This is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(readxl)
library(xlsx)
library(DT)

items <- read_excel("items.xlsx",col_names = F)
colnames(items) <- c("Items", "Euro", "Cost")


ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme('journal'),
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    tags$img(height = 118, width = 160, src="logo.jpg"),
                    br(),br(),
                       textInput('name','Name'),
                    br(),
                    selectizeInput(inputId = "item",
                                   label = "Item",
                                   choices = c(items$Items),
                                   options = list(
                                     placeholder = '',
                                     onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'))),
                    br(),
                    numericInput('number','Quantity',value = 1,step = 1),
                    br(),
                    numericInput('price','Price/pc',value = ''),
                    br(),
                    actionButton(inputId = "button", label = "Add", icon = icon("plus"),
                                 style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"),
                    
                    width = 3),
              mainPanel(DTOutput('out')))
                  )
                
                    


server <- function(input, output,session) {
   observeEvent(input$button,{
    order <- data.frame(read_excel("Order.xlsx"))
    price <- items[items$Items == input$item,][c(2,3)]
    order[nrow(order) + 1,] <- c(ifelse(input$name %in% order$Name,'',input$name),input$item,input$number,
                                 price,price[2]* input$number,input$price*input$number,
                                 (input$price*input$number) - (price[2]* input$number))
    
    write.xlsx(order,'order.xlsx')
    
  
   
    output$out<- renderDT({datatable(order)})
   })
    }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

items.xlsx

```
Items             Euro        Cost
some item          2.5         10
some item2         5           20
some item3         4           18
```

order.xlsx

```
Name   Item   Quantity   Euro   Cost   Total cost    Total price    Gain
```

can somebody know what is the cause for that and how to solve?
Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't recreate your exact app because I had trouble getting xlsx package to load on my system. I recreated a similar working example by saving the two excel files as CSV files and using readr read_csv and write_csv in place of your read_excel and write.xlsx. This version appears to work as you want it to but with csv output instead of excel. Having a read of the xlsx documentation I might have a guess that row names are being written out each time you write.xlsx and this is showing up when you read them back in. Could it be that you need to pass row.names = FALSE to your write.xlsx call?
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/xlsx.pdf

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(DT)
library(readr)

items <- readr::read_csv("items.csv",col_names = T)


ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme('journal'),
            sidebarLayout(
              sidebarPanel(
                tags$img(height = 118, width = 160, src="logo.jpg"),
                br(),br(),
                textInput('name','Name'),
                br(),
                selectizeInput(inputId = "item",
                               label = "Item",
                               choices = c(items$Items),
                               options = list(
                                 placeholder = '',
                                 onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue("");       }'))),
                br(),
                numericInput('number','Quantity',value = 1,step = 1),
                br(),
                numericInput('price','Price/pc',value = ''),
                br(),
                actionButton(inputId = "button", label = "Add", icon = icon("plus"),
                             style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"),
                
                width = 3),
              mainPanel(DTOutput('out')))
)




server <- function(input, output,session) {
  observeEvent(input$button,{
    order <- data.frame(read_csv("order.csv"))
    price <- items[items$Items == input$item,][c(2,3)]
    order[nrow(order) + 1,] <- c(ifelse(input$name %in% order$Name,'',input$name),input$item,input$number,
                             price,price[2]* input$number,input$price*input$number,
                             (input$price*input$number) - (price[2]* input$number))

    write_csv(order,'order.csv')



    output$out<- renderDT({datatable(order)})
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Graeme-diack, you are right. Now it works

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you! did you change to using CSV files or did you pass row.names = FALSE to your write.xlsx? Cheers, GD

Comment: I passed row.names = FALSE

Answer (score 0):

Try to perform data reading and data wrangling outside of the observer as shown below.

```
items <- read.table(text='"Items","Euro","Cost"
some item, 2.5, 10
some item2, 5,20
some item3, 4,18', header=TRUE, sep=",")


ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme('journal'),
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    tags$img(height = 118, width = 160, src="logo.jpg"),
                    br(),br(),
                    textInput('name','Name'),
                    br(),
                    selectizeInput(inputId = "item",
                                   label = "Item",
                                   choices = c(items$Items),
                                   options = list(
                                     placeholder = '',
                                     onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'))),
                    br(),
                    numericInput('number','Quantity',value = 1,step = 1),
                    br(),
                    numericInput('price','Price/pc',value = ''),
                    br(),
                    actionButton(inputId = "button", label = "Add", icon = icon("plus"),
                                 style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"),

                    width = 3),
                  mainPanel(DTOutput('out')))
)


server <- function(input, output,session) {

  order <- eventReactive(input$button,{
    req(input$number,input$price,input$name)
    order <- data.frame(read_excel("order.xlsx"))
    price <- items[items$Items == input$item,][c(2,3)]
    order[nrow(order) + 1,] <- c(ifelse(input$name %in% order$Name,'',input$name),input$item,input$number,
                                 price,price[2]* input$number,input$price*input$number,
                                 (input$price*input$number) - (price[2]* input$number))
    order
  })

  observeEvent(input$button,{  write.xlsx(order(),'order.xlsx') })

  output$out<- renderDT({datatable(order())})
   
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: I got the error : 
Error in : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable 
because order() cannot be subsetted

Comment: It didn't work with me either, the same problem exists

Comment: It works fine for me with `openxlsx` package.